# jquery post array data from HTML forms

Tags: javascript, jquery

In one of my HTML page, there are a few input fields with the same name attributes since I want to send them as an array to another PHP for back-end transactions.

Suppose the input field like below :

```
<input type="text" name="language_names[]" value="english">
<input type="text" name="language_names[]" value="french">
<input type="text" name="language_names[]" value="spanish">
```

Now I want to use Jquery to send this array? I am using the **.post()** method for this, I know for single value it could be send as **{key1: value1, key2:value2...}**, but for array How can I do it like this ? I guess it should be close to

```
{'language_names[]' : $('#input[name="language_names[]"]').val()}
```

But it doesn't work (I check the request body). Anyone can help ?

Comment: Have a look at jQuery serialize() http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need a simple array with the values of those specific input elements, you could use something like:

```
function getLanguageValues() {
    var language_names = [];
    $.each($("input[name=language_names\\[\\]]"), function (indexInArray, valueOfElement) {
        language_names.push($(valueOfElement).val());
    });
    return language_names;
}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/excentris/f9QBM/).

Answer (score 5):

Use serialize function of jquery like this

```
// This returns a json representation of your form values
$('#formid').serialize();
```

Comment: If I just want to send this array, not the whole form, how can I can this ?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can also do this :

```
{'language_names[]' : $('input[name=language_names\\[\\]]').serialize()}
```

Comment: I am expecting the serialize method will return an array of values in the **value** attribute. In my case, the array should contain "english", "french", "spanish", etc. However, with your proposed method, it's empty.